# Windows 10 can't access other PCs in LAN

Tags: windows-10, networking, windows-11, lan, error-correction

I've been having trouble for several days with a PC (let's call it "PC1") with Windows 10 Enterprise on an AsRock A55M-VS. Why enterprise you may ask? Because I already tried Pro, Home and even windows 11 of the same variants and with the same end result.

I always get this error (picture below) when trying to connect from PC1 to other Windows shared folders. I don't have this issue with any other device in my network.

[image: Dummy pic but exact error]

Things I've done:

- Network discovery is enabled
- Network set to private
- File and printer sharing is enabled for private and "all networks"
- Password access is disabled
- Enabled SMB 1.0/CIFS file sharing support in Windows features
- Disabled Internet protocol IPV6 (shouldn't be a problem but oh well)
- Tried a PCI network card
- Tried a PCI WiFi card

Services set to automatic and automatic (delayed):

- Function Discovery Provider Host
- Function Discovery Resource Publication
- SSDP Discovery
- UPnP Device Host

Symptoms:

1. PC1 can't access other PCs shared folders in the same LAN. Other PCs can access each other without issue. It's a fully working LAN with several Windows machines and a Linux file server. (In the following examples "LUCAS" is my main PC)
   [image: Got into my server, yet not into "LUCAS"]
2. If I `ping`  or `ping -4` from PC1 to other PCs in LAN I get a good response but still no access.
   [image: Ping and Ping -4 to PC in same LAN]
3. Other PCs in the same LAN can access shared folder from PC1 with no apparent issue but sometimes, randomly, it just  doesn't show up.
4. Other PCs in the same LAN can't "find" printers connected to PC1
5. Tried this in client's LAN and in my office's LAN. Same outcome everywhere.

I don't know what else to try. Could this be a hardware related issue?

Comment: I would first try a different Windows User Profile (Account). Set up the User, set up networking and attempt to access other machines. I have my machines all networked here.

Comment: Hi @John. Just tried your  suggestion and still didnt work. I created another user in PC1 and the outcome was exactly the same

Comment: There appears to be some serious damage to the Windows 10 operating system. Since not profile related you can try a Windows 10 Repair install

Comment: But the install is brand new. I've had this issue in the same machine with several windows versions allready. Idk waht to do anymore man...

Comment: Is there manufacturer hardware diagnostics that you can run?

Comment: Windows 10 is definitely coming to end of life. Perhaps replace it with a Windows 11 Pro machine

Comment: Already tried windows 11 pro but will do it again just to be sure. I just tried with a wifi USB dongle and nothing, same outcome. Thanks for your time John!

Comment: If there is a hardware issue on the machine, installing a different OS may not solve the issue

Comment: Try disabling Windows firewall to see if that makes a difference.  Also, double check the advanced sharing settings on PC1.  Have you tried accessing shared folders/hosts via IP address?  Make sure nothing goofy is enabled in local group policy too (with a new installation nothing should be enabled).  Does RDP work both ways to/from PC1?

Comment: I would have thought that installing Windows 11 on the same machine (apparently) would have reset all this